# In this example, why is there a loop in a server sent event?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server-sent-events

Example ([from this tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/06/real-time-rails-4-using-server-sent-events-with-authy-onetouch.html))

```
class AuthyController < ApplicationController
  def one_touch_status_live
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
    sse = SSE.new(response.stream, event: 'time')
    begin
      loop do
        sse.write({ :time => Time.now })
        sleep 1
      end
    rescue ClientDisconnected
    ensure
      sse.close
    end
  end
end
```

I tested it in my local server, and I was getting a continuous stream of `Time.now` even without the loop clause... or am I doing something wrong?